# AS3 - Is there a way to retrieve the entire package and class name as a String?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, class

In a class I want to retrieve the package + class name of the current class as a String.

For example, within a class named `Inhabitant` within package `terra.environment` I might want to go:

```
trace(someSaughtPropertyName); // terra.environment.Inhabitant
```

Is this possible, or is this stuff all abolished/irrelevant after compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use `getQualifiedClassName` in `flash.utils`:

```
trace(getQualifiedClassName(this));
```

The result will be in the form:

```
terra.environment::Inhabitant
```